# Object is not spawning as per the given coordinates under Image Marker in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, unity-xr

I am creating two scenes in unity.
In Scene 1, first, with the help of Image Marker, I will set a zero coordinate gameobject, and based on that I am instantiate gameobjects on screen touch and saving there coordinates in csv.

In Scene 2, again with the help of Image Marker, I will set a zero coordinate gameobject, and based on that I am instantiating gameobjects based on the coordinates saved in csv.

In both of the scene, Image Marker is the parent of the zero coordinates gameobject , under which the other gameobject are created as child. And my plane is in x-z axis and y-axis is the height. I have used Vuforia for the image marker.

Now, the issue is with the scene 2. When I try to spawn gameobject based on csv file, the object doesn't appear in the same place. It is slightly high and moved toward left side. When I try this in the editor, it works well, but not in my device.

Is there some additional work that I have to do for proper alignment, as I have kept the same setup for both saving and receiving data?

If any extra information is required, I will try to edit it to add.

Comment: check all the scales are 1,1,1?

Comment: yes, every thing is 1,1,1

Comment: I don't know how to solve this yet, but the problem is due to the AR Plane which is causing the problem as the earth plane is not straight, which causes it problem when re- place the objects in the selected coordinate point.